# Set the pager to "auto" at grid init in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid, pager

After an extensive search through StackOverflow and SlickGrid docs, I didn't find a way to set the grid Pager automatically to "auto" at grid init.
The solution I found is to modify  slick.pager.js at line 70 adding  `id='autopager'`  in:

```
$settings.append(
"<span class='slick-pager-settings-expanded' style='display:none'>Show:
<a data=0>All</a><a data='-1' id='autopager'>Auto</a><a data=25>25</a>
<a data=50>50</a><a data=100>100</a></span>");
```

So I can trigger che "click" event on the "auto" link in the pager
with one line of code:
    `$('#autopager').trigger('click');`

It works well for me and maybe it could be useful for others. 
There is some better solution not involving hacking the core of SlickGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below code. But it will be the fixed value for pageSize.

```
data_view.setPagingOptions({pageSize: 20})
```

Comment: Thank you Hein. At the end I used your solution beacause there is a bug in the "auto" feature: the scrollbar still appear whatever grid dimension I choose.